# Change view width constraint

Tags: swift, autolayout

I set up width of UIView like this:

```
contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(scrollWidth())).isActive = true
```

Now I want to change that width. The question is: how to remove old constraint and add new? I did create `NSLayoutConstraint` like this

```
scrollWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: contentView,
    attribute: .width,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: nil,
    attribute: .notAnAttribute,
    multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: CGFloat(scrollWidth())
)
```

How to set that constraint for `UIView` for changing later?

Comment: for your case you don't have to remove old constraint and add another

Answer (score 3):

First use this better and short  and assign a reference to it

```
var widCon:NSLayoutConstraint! 

widCon = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(scrollWidth()))
widCon.isActive = true
```

instead of `NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView,`  then  Change it's constant

```
widCon.constant = ////
```